# Android SQLite could no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

I followed this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Now I followed everything to the letter as seen in my DatabaseHelper class:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import slo.bankomati.models.Atm;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * SQLite Database Interface 
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
  // OPERATING VARS
  private static String  DB_PATH = "/data/data/slo.bankomati.core/databases/";
  private static String  DB_NAME = "nessus";
  private SQLiteDatabase DATABASE;
  private final Context  CONTEXT;

  // DATABASE TABLES
  private static final String TABLE_ATM = "atms";

  /**
   * Stores a reference to Context class
   * to allow access to application associated resources.
   */
  public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
  {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.CONTEXT = context;
  }

  /**
   * DATABASE TABLE - CRUD METHODS
   */
  public String[] getDBNames(){
    String[] result = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT name FROM " + DB_NAME); 
        sb.append("WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' ");
        sb.append("UNION ALL ");
        sb.append("SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master "); 
        sb.append("WHERE type IN ('table','view') ");
        sb.append("ORDER BY 1");

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        result = new String[c.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            result[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Returns all entries associated with
   * table: Atms
   */
  public List<Atm> getAllAtms()
  {
    // Reserve array for entries
    List<Atm> all = new ArrayList<Atm>();

    // Prepare SQL statement
    String statement = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ATM;

    // Fetch db instance
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(statement, null);

    int LIMIT_COUNTER = 0;

    // Add all retrieved entries to array
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
      do {
        // Map table to object
        Atm atm = new Atm(
            cursor.getInt(0),           // atm
            cursor.getString(1),        // owner
            cursor.getString(2),        // entity
            cursor.getString(3),        // address
            cursor.getInt(4),           // zip
            cursor.getString(5),        // city
            cursor.getInt(6),           // print
            cursor.getInt(7),           // deposit_unit
            cursor.getInt(8),           // gsm
            cursor.getInt(9),           // bills
            cursor.getInt(10),          // mastercard
            cursor.getInt(11),          // visa
            cursor.getInt(12),          // dubers
            cursor.getInt(13),          // transactions
            cursor.getInt(14),          // transfers
            cursor.getInt(15),          // deposit
            cursor.getDouble(16),       // latitude
            cursor.getDouble(17)        // longitude
        );

        // Store object


        if(LIMIT_COUNTER < 5)
        {
          all.add(atm);
        } 
        LIMIT_COUNTER++;

      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return all;
  }

  /**
   * DATABASE - CREATE - UPDATE METHODS
   */

  public synchronized void close()
  {
    if(DATABASE != null)
      DATABASE.close();

    super.close();
  }

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }


  /**
   * Create a empty database on and override it with
   * applications own database. 
   */
  public void createDatabase()
  {
    if(!checkDatabase())
    {
      getReadableDatabase();

      try {
        // Atempt to copy over the database
        copyDatabase();

      } catch (Exception e)  {
        // Could not copy database
        // TODO: Substitute Log for production version
        Log.w("ILG", "Could not copy the database");
      } 
    }
  }

  /**
   * Checks if our database already exists on our system
   * in order to avoid a copy over.
   * 
   * @return boolean
   */
  private boolean checkDatabase()
  {
    SQLiteDatabase test = null;

    try {
      // Attempt to open local database
      test = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // Exception caught database does not exsist
    } finally {
      // Close database
      if(test != null)
        test.close();
    }

    return (test != null) ? true : false;
  }

  /**
   * Overrides newly created empty database
   * with our own database.
   */
  private void copyDatabase()
  {
    try {
      // Open input file stream from our database
      InputStream fis = CONTEXT.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

      // Open output file stream for our empty database
      OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

      // Allocate 1024 bytes for file transfer per cycle
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

      // Reference to the amount of byte read
      int block;

      // Read source until EOF
      while( (block = fis.read(buffer)) > 0 )
        fos.write(buffer, 0, block);

      // Close FIS and FOS streams
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
      fis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Could not override the database
      // TODO: Replace with write production version
      Log.w("ILG", "Could not write to destenation.");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Open source database.
   */
  public void openDatabase()
  {
    try {
      DATABASE = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: Replace with write production version
      Log.w("ILG", "Could not open database.");
    }
  }

}
```

Problem is whenever I run this I get a no such table error. Afterwards I added getDBNames method to check what table names actually do exist in my database but it just return a null String[] array.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use `SQLiteAssetHelper` rather than rolling your own implementation based upon that blog post: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @CommonsWare Tried this SQLiteAssetHelper lib still same problem.

Comment: `c.moveToFirst(); ... while (c.moveToNext()) {` <= doing this you are skipping one row ... remove `c.moveToFirst();` ... and for your sanity return to `SQLiteAssetHelper`

Comment: @Selvin same problem persists in SQLiteAssetHelper

Comment: Are you sure use select on database itself? try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430950/sqlite-how-to-get-all-table-names-in-database)